# URL in webservice with drupal

Tags: web-services, drupal, drupal-7

I'm new to working with web service and drupal, and I don't understand some things.
My problem is that I have a service with retrieve to get the user data 
http://miweb.es/endpoint/app_user/{EMAIL}
I need pass a email to retrieve the data, but I can't put a dot (.) because I get a error 406

406 Not Acceptable : Unknown or unsupported response format.

Advance thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can not have a period in the url because Drupal Services uses this to determine the response format but you have a few options to pass the email would be in the header, in the body, as a get variable.

If you nee to keep the url format you could replace the period with a rewrite rule in your .htaccess

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But If I pass the email in the body, I can't use retrieve? or I have use other operation. Sorry for my bad English

Comment: How are you creating your end point? If you are defining them in a custom module you will be using hook_services_resources, this function requires a source array where you define the source of you variables